# Show that if $(m,n) = 1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lfloor \frac{mk}{n} \rfloor=\frac{(n-1)(m-1)}{2}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $(m,n) = 1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lfloor \frac{mk}{n} \rfloor=\frac{(n-1)(m-1)}{2}.$

This problem occurs in chapter on GCD, and allied topics in an Elementary number theory book.

My understanding of the problem at hand is: 
 $\hspace3mm$ $\frac{m}{n}$ forms a proper fraction, although the same cannot be said if it is multiplied by a natural (till $n-1$), unless $n$ is a prime,which is not stated here. That's all, and the significance of the floor function here confuses me totally. Although, the r.h.s. expression resembles the area of a triangle, with one reduced from both $m,n$. Again, it is confusing enough.

If I could be at least be given significance / meaning of the question, then it would make it easier to comprehend.

*Addendum* In wake of answer by @mathworker21, I 'have' found the answer and my attempt is as follows:
 As there is summation of values of $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$, it is obvious that arithmetic progression sum is taken up, with distance = 1, number of values = n-1. So, the given expression should be: $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$
=> $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q_k= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{mk}{n} -  \frac{n(n-1)}{2n} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{mk}{n}= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q_k + \frac{n(n-1)}{2n}$.

The quotients for $\frac{k}{n}$ would be all zero, as $1 \le k \lt n$, so the quotients can be ignored. But, $\frac{mk}{n}$ needs analysis:

I take a simple example of $m = 5, n = 13, k \in {1,2,...,n-1}$.
The different terms are: $\frac{5}{13}, \frac{10}{13}, \frac{15}{13}, \frac{20}{13}, \frac{25}{13}, \frac{30}{13}, \frac{35}{13}, \frac{40}{13}, \frac{45}{13}, \frac{50}{13}, \frac{55}{13}, \frac{60}{13}$.
One thing is certain, that all quotients are not zero, but how to use this fact in proving answer is unclear. An alternate representation for quotient can be : 
 $\lfloor \frac{mk}{n} \rfloor$.

Trying to work backwards to get a clue: 
As the question is about the sum of quotients, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lfloor \frac{mk}{n} \rfloor$ =   $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{mk}{n} - \frac{(n-1)}{2} = \frac{(n-1)(m-1)}{2}$.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{mk}{n} = \frac{(n-1)(m-1)}{2} + \frac{(n-1)}{2} = => \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{mk}{n} = \frac{(n-1)(m)}{2}$.

The fact about the $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{mk}{n}$ being equal to $\frac{(n-1)(m)}{2}$ can be easily seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $1 \le k \le n-1$, write $mk = q_kn + r_k$ where $0 \le r_k < n-1$. Our sum is then $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} q_k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} mk-r_k$. But note that $r_k \equiv mk \pmod{n}$ so since $(m,n) = 1$, the residues $\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ are just permuted by multiplying by $m$. So, $\{r_1,\dots,r_{n-1}\} = \{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ and therefore $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} r_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$. I'll let you finish by just putting everything together now.

Comment: @jiten you should split up the sum into $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}mk$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} r_k$. For the first term, pull out the $m$ and sum $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$. The second term is basically the same

Comment: Just now I solved it, it was my folly not to divide the remainder summation term by $n$. You can also check my edited OP for any possible errors, or improvements.

Comment: Looks good! I think you are over complicating a bit however. Just note $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{mk}{n} = \frac{m}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k$ and you already calculated the sum as $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, you have a better idea still. I am so thankful for correcting this lack.